# POST data in JSON format

Tags: javascript, json, post, xmlhttprequest

I have some data that I need to convert to JSON format and then POST it with a JavaScript function.

```
<body onload="javascript:document.myform.submit()">
<form action="https://www.test.net/Services/RegistrationService.svc/InviteNewContact" method="post" name="myform">
  <input name="firstName" value="harry" />
  <input name="lastName" value="tester" />
  <input name="toEmail" value="testtest@test.com" />
</form>
</body>
```

This is the way the post looks now. I need it submit the values in JSON format and do the POST with JavaScript.

Comment: What structure should the JSON data have? Just `{"firstName":"harry", "lastName":"tester", "toEmail":"testtest@test.com"}`?

Comment: Yes the data would be in the format you described! thanks for the responses!

Answer (score 178):

Not sure if you want jQuery.

```
var form;

form.onsubmit = function (e) {
  // stop the regular form submission
  e.preventDefault();

  // collect the form data while iterating over the inputs
  var data = {};
  for (var i = 0, ii = form.length; i < ii; ++i) {
    var input = form[i];
    if (input.name) {
      data[input.name] = input.value;
    }
  }

  // construct an HTTP request
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open(form.method, form.action, true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');

  // send the collected data as JSON
  xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));

  xhr.onloadend = function () {
    // done
  };
};
```

Comment: I think this is a good, clean, concise example of how to get the job done in 20 lines of code, without 100K of framework.

Comment: @IanKuca Thanks:) I was wondering if we can send the json data without urlencode the data? I mean I want to send data like `"cmd":"<img src=0 onerror=alert(1)>"` not `%3Cimg+src%3D0+onerror%3Dalert%281%29%3E`

Comment: @liweijian You should go with whatever `JSON.stringify` returns.

Comment: @IanKuca It seems that the post data was encoded by `html form` not `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: @liweijian you'd need to urldecode the form values first if that's the case

Comment: There is no jQuery tag in this question.

Comment: Help Needed---> .   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43673006/javascript-post-request-as-json

Comment: Does the request header have content type json? Because am doing the same and the content type is getting set as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and my call breaks as the server expects json. How to resolve that?

Comment: How would one attach this code to the actual html form?  It would be helpful to add the basic html that can use the above code.

Comment: `onloadend` should probably be put before `.send()`, it's unlikely that will cause issues. But, in general it's a good idea to put your event handlers *before* the code that fires the event that uses those handlers.

Answer (score 29):

Here is an example using [jQuery](http://jquery.com)...

```
 <head>
   <title>Test</title>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.json.org/json2.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function() {
       var frm = $(document.myform);
       var dat = JSON.stringify(frm.serializeArray());

       alert("I am about to POST this:\n\n" + dat);

       $.post(
         frm.attr("action"),
         dat,
         function(data) {
           alert("Response: " + data);
         }
       );
     });
   </script>
</head>
```

The jQuery [serializeArray](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/serializeArray) function creates a Javascript object with the form values.  Then you can use [JSON.stringify](http://www.json.org/js.html) to convert that into a string, if needed.  And you can remove your body onload, too.

Comment: As a matter of fact, the serialize function converts form data to a JSON object.

Comment: Josh, the example on jQuery shows otherwise: Looks more like a standard query-string than like JSON.

Comment: You guys are right.  I've updated the answer accordingly.  Thanks!

Comment: Is there anyway you could give me anymore details then this. A full blow example if possible. thanks again

Comment: Josh I wish you would have left the original code in also. Showed New and Old Code.

Comment: This is a good example, however according the title this should be performed using javascript, not a javascript library (like jQuery in this case)

Comment: You are, of course, welcome to do it the hard way. Everyone else uses jQuery.

Comment: The question asks how to POST data using _javascript_, not the jquery library. This answers the wrong question.

Comment: @PaulMurrayCbr jQuery is not needed anymore. 20 lines of code > 132142343 lines of unnecessary framework code.

Answer (score 3):

Using the new [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/FormData) object (and other ES6 stuff), you can do this to turn your entire form into JSON:

```js
let data = {};
let formdata = new FormData(theform);
for (let tuple of formdata.entries()) data[tuple[0]] = tuple[1];
```

and then just `xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));` like in Jan's original answer.

Comment: That won't work. A FormData objects do not usefully stringify to JSON.