# How to pass JSON to another screen in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a webpage (index.html) with a JSON object and a button. When I click the button I need to open another webpage (first.html) and send this JSON object from 1st screen to 2nd screen.

I used:

```
location.href = "first.html".
var myJSON = {"user" : [{"name" : "Ajay" , "age":"20"},{"name" : "Vicky" , "age":"25"}]};
```

And I don't need to use storage option and need pure JavaScript code. No JQuery.

Comment: How about using Cookie ?

Comment: Cookie or local/sessionstorage. The querystring has a limited length so forget about that.

Comment: is there any other methods other than cookie or localstorages? Like Jquery's $.mobile.changePage("first.html", {data:{param1:'myJSON'}});

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for there is form submission. Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13038218/1756598

that `var myJson` is not doing anything there anyways because before it gets there you have gone to another page.