# Sending form data as JSON - Browser changing Content-Type

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, http-headers

I'm trying to create an HTML page that can submit the form data to the server in the form of JSON. I consulted the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255948/post-data-in-json-format-with-javascript) and am using the following code to do this:

```
<head>
   <title>Test</title>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.json.org/json2.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function() {
       var frm = $(document.myform);
       var dat = JSON.stringify(frm.serializeArray());

       alert("I am about to POST this:\n\n" + dat);

       $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          data: dat,
          success: function(){},
          dataType: "json",
          contentType : "application/json"
        });
     });
   </script>
</head>

<body onload="javascript:document.myform.submit()">
<form action="http://www.foo.com/" method="post" name="myform">
    <input name="firstName" value="harry" />
    <input name="lastName" value="tester" />
    <input name="toEmail" value="testtest@test.com" />
</form>
```

However, if I intercept the request using Burp proxy tool, I can see that for some reason, the Content-Type becomes `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as soon as the request leaves the browser. Here's a screenshot of the request:

[image]

I would like to know why is this happening with the request? Why is the browser changing the Content-Type in the request? Is there a better way to do this?

PS: I've tried this without jQuery (using XHR as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13038218/1382832)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your jQuery `$.ajax` request has no URL specified, so it is just hitting your own website and doing nothing. Meanwhile the `onload="javascript:document.myform.submit()"` property in your HTML is using the browser's regular form submission, which is in fact `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

What you probably want to do is get rid of that statement and use jQuery's `.submit` to handle the form submission. You also want to specify the URL in the jQuery AJAX request.

Try something like this:

```
<head>
   <title>Test</title>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.json.org/json2.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      $('#myform').submit(function() {
         var frm = $(this);
         var dat = JSON.stringify(frm.serializeArray()); 

         alert("I am about to POST this:\n\n" + dat);

         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "http://www.foo.com/",
             data: dat,
             success: function(){},
             dataType: "json",
             contentType : "application/json"
         });
      });   
   </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="myform">
        <input name="firstName" value="harry" />
        <input name="lastName" value="tester" />
        <input name="toEmail" value="testtest@test.com" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: I see the problem with my code. However, I'm still not able to make a POST request because the cross domain requests are forbidden by the browsers.

Comment: right, you can do a get with jsonp but you will need to modify the server side code to make a cross domain post

Answer (score 1):

Also you are stringifying an array not an object.  Below is what I would do for this:

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>Test</title>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function() {
    //var frm = $(document.myform);
    //var dat = JSON.stringify(frm.serializeArray());
    var dat = {
        firstName: $('#firstName').val(),
        lastName: $('#lastName').val(),
        email: $('#email').val()
    }
    $('#myform').submit(function(e) {
        $.ajax({
            datatype : "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            type: "POST",
            url: '/local-url-to-controller.php',
            data: JSON.stringify(dat),
            success: function() {},
            error: function() {},
        });
        // Stops browser refresh
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    // Submit on document ready
    $('#myform').submit();
 });
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="myform" id="myform">
    <input name="firstName" value="harry" id="firstName" />
    <input name="lastName" value="tester" id="lastName" />
    <input name="toEmail" value="testtest@test.com" id="email" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

If you are set on using serialized form data, try something like this:
[Convert form data to JavaScript object with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-js-object-with-jquery)

Comment: tested and this works fine, just update the url in the ajax and you're good to go.

Comment: It is not sending the data to the server. It is just sending an OPTIONS request to the server and that's it.

Comment: What is the response of the OPTIONS request from the server? If the server says it doesn't accept the Content-Type then jQuery won't continue with the request

Comment: It's giving a proper response for the request.

Comment: Try and see if jQuery is giving you an error in the `error` function.