# Posting JSON string to login to a website using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, json, authentication, token

I am trying to write a javascript that can help me post JSON data to the website's json_server.php page to login successfully.

An example of the JSON data will be as follows:

```
{
    "method":"validateUserAccountWithUsernameAndPassword",
    "id":100000,
    "params":[
        "testname",
        "password",
        "empid"
    ]
}
```

There are two scenarios:

1)  I tired the method mentioned in the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255948/post-data-in-json-format-with-javascript) using javascript/ajax, but all I got was a blank page. This was tested by running the script from notepad++ to firefox browser.

2)  I used the above JSON on a chrome extension called [POSTMAN](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en) and it worked fine, passing the JSON string which returned with 200 OK, but not sure how it when through, as I see lots of tokens been passed.

I need to get a working javascript that can post JSON string successfully that will help me login successfully like in scenario 1 ?

Comment: Are you aware you're sending a plaintext object containing both username & password, there?

Comment: What is your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Isn't a blank page what you are looking for ?

I mean what's the difference between it and a simple 200 OK response ?

What I see here is :

- You POST your JSON
- the php page goes through it, the credentials are corrects
- the php returns a blank response with 200 OK status to tell you that you are correctly identified (maybe it creates a cookie at the same time with a token, maybe not)

Do you have any doc about what json_server.php is supposed to answer ?

Comment: Please do not ask questions in an answer.

Comment: Yhea, I'd like to right comments instead, but I don't have 50 rep' points yet. Plus rhetorical questions aren't really questions.

Comment: Didn't say I couldn't, yet the only way to earn points at my level are by having answers upvoted so ...

Comment: Then post answers instead of questions :) Or go edit some posts in the review queue. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252133/50-reputation-points-to-make-comments and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/six-simple-tips-to-get-stack-overflow-reputation-fast You'll probably find that this 'answer' will get deleted at some point.

Comment: Again, how a rhetorical question isn't an answer ? Plus I'm not authorized to edit anything ...

Comment: Apologies, if my question was not clear. I have made some edits to help explain the scenario in a better manner.

Comment: So what shall I do if I want to help Ajov Crowe here but I don't have those 50 rep' points required ?