# How to build a form to POST this data example

Tags: html

I can send this successfully using the Postman Chrome extension with RAW data as below. How do I to build a HTML form, with fields to input message/badge/status and POST the data?

```html
POST /rest/push/msg HTTP/1.1
Host: api.appery.io
X-Appery-Push-API-Key: myKey
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
{"payload":{"message":"Rockets important message","badge":"1"},"status":"sent"}
```

Comment: Are these the `request` headers or the `response` headers?

Comment: @dbf — It starts with `POST /rest/push/msg HTTP/1.1` so it has to be a request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.

There are a few [ways that a form can encode data](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fs-enctype), but JSON is not currently one of them. There is a [proposal](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-json-forms/) to change that, but I'm not aware of any browser implementation in the wild.

Aside from that, a regular form submission doesn't support the addition of custom request headers (such as `X-Appery-Push-API-Key`).

If you want to make that request from a webpage, you'll have to [construct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255948/post-data-in-json-format-with-javascript) it using JavaScript and send it with the [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) object (which would be subject to the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)).