# Jersey 2.22 and json unsupported media type

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest

I'm creating a rest web service and i want to consume a json/xml object. I'm using jersey and when i try to post the request i obtain a 415 error unsopported media type.
Here is the pom dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.22</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>2.22</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.22</version>
    </dependency>
```

the web.xml

```
servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>
            provider packages
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature; 
            org.glassfish.jersey.server.filter.RolesAllowedDynamicFeature,
            org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.JacksonFeature
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and the webservice

```
@POST
@Path("FooPath")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public void insertFoo(FooClass fc){
    System.out.println(fc.getFoo());
}
```

anyone can help me?

Comment: so how do you post the request? Its content-type is probably not xml nor json.

Comment: for test i post the request with a html page. it's a simple form with this value method="post" enctype='application/json'

Answer (score 1):

You try to send a  `application/json` request using a form submit with the forms `enctype` set to `application/json`.

Unfortunately `enctype` only supports [these values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form):

- `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (the default)
- `multipart/form-data`
- `text/plain` (in HTML5)

The browser silently ignores the enctype and you server rejects the request since it is most likely `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

In order to send the request as json you need to create an appropriate Ajax request from Javascript. Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255948/post-data-in-json-format) how to do that.

Comment: @Luca I think you should first verify (e.g. using Firebug) that the content-type in your original request was not the intended `application/json` as I analyzed. This ends this question. If you have problems to get the Ajax request working you should post a new question.

Comment: i tried with this but doesn't work

var frm = $(document.myform);
var dat = JSON.stringify(frm.serializeArray());

alert("I am about to POST this:\n\n" + dat);

$.post(
 frm.attr("action"),
 dat,
 function(data) {
   alert("Response: " + data);
 }
);