# Should I use `php://input` and/or `$_POST`?

Tags: php, ajax, api, http, post

I'm building API with the following structure:

- method `POST`
- uri `/words`.
- body `{"word":"example"}`.

This request should add word to database and if I testing it by [`httpie`](https://httpie.org/) everything is ok.

```
$ http POST localhost:8000/words word="new word2"

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: application/json
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8080
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost:8000
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.12-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1
{
    "test": {
        "method": "POST",
        "input": {
            "word": "new word2"
        }, 
        "post": []
    }, 
    "words": {
        "id": "581f2f118b0414307476f7b3", 
        "word": "new word2"
    }
}
```

In `test` I placed variable obtained in `php` by:

```
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
$input =  json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);
$post =  $_POST;
```

We can see that `$_POST` is empty. If I use javascript:

```
$(form).submit(function(e) {
    var url = "http://localhost:8000/words"; 
    var data = {"word" : form.elements["word"].value };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data)
        {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data)); 
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

I obtain the following console log:

```
{
   "test":{
      "method":"POST",
      "input":null,
      "post":{
         "word":"word from form"
      }
   },
   "words":{
      "id":"581f34b28b0414307476f7b6",
      "word":null
   }
}
```

Now `input` is empty. Word is null because I am processing `$input["word"]`, from `php://input`. My questions:

- Should I process `$_POST`, or check both variable?
- How about best practices of using these methods?
- Can I send `php://input` from browser or `$_POST` from command line toll like `httpie`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your manually constructed example and your JavaScript example are not equivalent.

In the first you are sending JSON encoded data with an application/json content-type.

In the second, you are passing a JavaScript object to jQuery and allowing it to follow it's default behaviour, which is to encod it using the application/x-www-form-urlencoded format and use that as the content type (just like submitting a regular HTML form would do).

PHP supports application/x-www-form-urlencoded data in POST requests, but not JSON.

> Should I process $_POST, or check both variable?

If you are sending application/x-www-form-urlencoded data or another format supported by PHP, then use `$_POST`. Otherwise you need to get the raw data from `php://input` and parse it yourself.

> Can I send php://input from browser

See [POST data in JSON format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255948/post-data-in-json-format)

> $_POST from command line toll like httpie?

See [the httpie documentation](https://httpie.org/docs#regular-forms):

> ```
> http --form POST api.example.org/person/1 name='John Smith'
> ```

Comment: Wow! Great answer! Than You very much.