# Sending Json Data to Spring Controller

Tags: java, angularjs, json, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to send json data from angular post to spring controller, but getting 404 in console :

> POST
>   http://localhost:8080/app/orderDetails/saveOrder/[object%20Object],[object%20Object]
>   404 (Not Found)

**JS**

```
var i=0;
var j = ngCart.getCart().items.length;
$scope.list=[];
for(i;i<j;i++){
    $scope.list.push({
          'id': ngCart.getCart().items[i]._id,
          'quantity':ngCart.getCart().items[i]._quantity
        });
    }
 $http.post("/app/orderDetails/saveOrder/"+$scope.list)
```

**Java(Spring)**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveOrder/list",headers="Accept=application/json")

public @ResponseBody Object saveOrder(@PathVariable List list){
}
```

Comment: @ Pratyush Pranjal Problem is with JS as it's not creating URL properly\

Comment: @Pratyush Pranjal, You are not creating a valid post request...refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255948/post-data-in-json-format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `List` as `PathVariable`. Make it `RequestBody` instead and fix your JS code to send `$scope.list` as a body, not append it to url:

```
-$http.post("/app/orderDetails/saveOrder/"+$scope.list)
+$http.post("/app/orderDetails/saveOrder", $scope.list);
```

Also create a wrapper object with `id` and `quantity` fields, something like:

```
public class CartItem {
    private Long id;
    private Long quantity;
    //getters and setters
}
```

Then you'll be able to parameterize your `List` with this object:

```
- public @ResponseBody Object saveOrder(@PathVariable List list){
+ public @ResponseBody Object saveOrder(@RequestBody List<CartItem> list){
```

Comment: Just a suggestion, but I would also add that `@PathVariable` is looking/for/a/path vs an object in the body

Comment: @Brian yeah it is a good idea if the same method is used for both 'POST' and 'PUT' operations. It is mapped for all operations but something tells me that it is used for 'POST' only.

Answer (score 3):

You should replace @PathVariable with @Request Body and fix your js code to send list as part of the request body (instead of adding it to the path).