# Java Spring Controller handling a ridiculous url

Tags: java, controller

Okay so I am using a payment service called Thrive cart, I am doing this for a membership website I'm creating. When the user has paid I want them to be redirected to a URL where I can use that data to update the current users information.

The data that get's sent in the params is insane:

http://localhost:5000/user/welcome?thrivecart%5Baccount_id%5D=3196&thrivecart%5Baccount_name%5D=testacount&thrivecart%5Bcustomer%5D%5Bemail%5D=testname8%40gmail.com&thrivecart%5Bcustomer%5D%5Baddress%5D%5Bcountry%5D=GB&thrivecart%5Bcustomer%5D%5Baddress%5D%5Bzip%5D=pe303wu&thrivecart%5Border%5D%5B0%5D%5Bt%5D=product&thrivecart%5Border%5D%5B0%5D%5Bid%5D=6&thrivecart%5Border%5D%5B0%5D%5Bn%5D=Monthly+membership&thrivecart%5Border%5D%5B0%5D%5Bp%5D=799&thrivecart%5Border%5D%5B0%5D%5Bq%5D=1&thrivecart%5Border%5D%5B0%5D%5Bpo%5D=60120&thrivecart%5Border%5D%5B1%5D%5Bt%5D=product&thrivecart%5Border%5D%5B1%5D%5Bid%5D=6&thrivecart%5Border%5D%5B1%5D%5Bn%5D=Monthly+membership&thrivecart%5Border%5D%5B1%5D%5Bp%5D=799&thrivecart%5Border%5D%5B1%5D%5Bq%5D=1&thrivecart%5Border%5D%5B1%5D%5Bpo%5D=60120&thrivecart%5Border_currency%5D=GBP&thrivecart%5Border_id%5D=1041278&thrivecart%5Border_tax%5D=0.2&thrivecart%5Border_tax_id%5D=gb&thrivecart%5Border_total%5D=799&thrivecart%5Bpayment_processor%5D=paypal&thrivecart%5Bproduct_id%5D=6&thrivecart%5Bpurchases%5D%5B0%5D=6&thrivecart%5Bpurchases%5D%5B1%5D=6&thrivecart_hash=a5b711d2288b4cb587511811bc0a3473

So far I've set up a simple controller which doesn't get hit:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/welcome", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void welcomeMember(@PathVariable String data) {

        System.out.println(data);
    }   
}
```

How do I deal with crazy data like this? Do I have to specific each path param?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, what you seem to get are not path elements but request parameters, so you will need @RequestParam annotations to get the values.

Since there are so many request parameters, I would also recommend to take just one parameter, a `Map<String, String>`. That Map will contain all the parameters as key/value pairs, for example:

- key: "thrivecart[account_id]"
- value: "3196"

If you're not sure whether you receive a POST or a GET request, you can also add a second parameter to receive the `HttpMethod`.

Change your RestController to:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/welcome")
    public void welcomeMember(@RequestParam Map<String, String> data, HttpMethod method) {
        System.out.println(method);
        System.out.println(data);
    }   
}
```

Comment: @user3667111 maybe your not receiving a POST request but a GET request. I've updated the sample code so that it works with both POST and GET

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a problem with how the rest api is called from the service consumer side.

try sending the data in a request body rather then as a param. This way you can use a POJO to handle the data.

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1:** So far I've set up a simple controller which doesn't get hit:

As per your URL http://localhost:5000/user/welcome "user" seems to be your projects context name. Try removing `@RequestMapping("/user")` from your class.

Also, instead of`@PathVariable String data` use `@RequestParam Map<String,String> params`. `@PathVariable String data` is used when data is part of url but in your case it's parameter. Final code should be like below.

```
    @RestController
    public class UserController {
        @RequestMapping(value = "/welcome", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public void welcomeMember(@RequestParam Map<String,String> params ) {
            for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()){
             //This will print all paramters name and their value
             System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "-" + entry.getValue());
            }
        }   
    }
```

**Question 2:** *How do I deal with crazy data like this? Do I have to specific each path param?*

I will suggest to follow standard practice. Send data in json format. There are different ways for this depend upon front end technology you are using. One way is [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255948/post-data-in-json-format)